# How to handle security on spring mvc back end with webapp and android app?

Tags: java, cookies, token, servlet-filters

We have to design a simple web application. We have a simple user model class with a username, password and email. Now we want to add some SIMPLE security to this login. I have read a few things about cookies, tokens and servletfilters, but I have no idea what to do concretely.

Basically what we want is:
-> Somehow keep track of a logged in user through our application.

It is written in java with spring-hibernate, the user is stored in a mysql database.
When a user logs in we check if the user that has been retrieved matches the password that has been typed in.

So if someone could point us to a simple tutorial where we can implement a simple thing liek this, it'd be greatly aprpeciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of implementing something on your own, try using an existing and proven solution like spring security, adding a simple user login form and remember me functionality is a matter of configuration in your context XML, Try this [tutorial](http://ananthchellathurai.blogspot.de/2013/12/spring-mvc-3-spring-security-hibernate.html).

If you need an alternative then you could also use [Apache Shiro](https://shiro.apache.org/spring.html).